# Declaration of sub-class must be compatible with parent class

Tags: php, oop

I know a sub-class is supposed to have the same data types for an abstract parent. But I have no such specific thing declared. Just a function, which the sub-class did declare. All the other sub-classes have no error but the Triangle one.

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract function getArea();
}

class Square extends Shape {
    protected $length = 4;

    public function getArea () {
        return pow($this->length, 2);
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    protected $radius = 5;

    public function getArea() {
        return M_PI * pow($this->radius, 2);
    }
}

class Triangle extends Shape {
    protected $base = 3;
    protected $height = 14;

    public function getArea($base, $height) {
        return .5 * $this->base * $this->height;
    }
}

(new Triangle)->getArea();
```

Why is it throwing me the following error?

> Declaration of Triangle::getArea() must be compatible with Shape::getArea().

Comment: Use `func_get_args` in your `getArea` method of the `Triangle` class, you've declared this method to have two required arguments whereas the parent class' `getArea` method has no required arguments - of course it's going to tell you the declaration is different. I don't even see why you need those two arguments in `getArea` method, you're not using them...

Comment: Why is it throwing me a "Declaration of Triangle::getArea() must be compatible with Shape::getArea().

Comment: You have the `getArea` function defined as  `getArea()` in the Shape abstract but as `getArea($base, $height)` in the Triangle class. Since you're extending the Shape abstract, the functions must match.

Comment: @Eihwaz I don't get how you would go about adding func_get_args in the class. Can you show me how you'd do it? I'm still fairly new.

Comment: @Django Ignore that. The function doesn't need any arguments.

Comment: @Django I wrote about `func_get_args` before you've edited your post. I don't think you need $base and $height arguments at all, method `getArea` of `Triangle` should be declared as `getArea()`, not `getArea($base, $height)`. If you DO need $base and $height arguments to be passed to this method, you may use `getArea($base = null, $height = null)`, thus making these arguments optional.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error, because your method's footprint has changed. Instead of passing the parameters in the method, they should be passed in the constructor:

```
class Triangle extends Shape {
    private $base;
    private $height;


    public function __construct($base, $height)
    {
        $this->base = (int) $base;
        $this->height = (int) $height;
    }

    public function getArea($base, $height) 
    {
        return 0.5 * $this->base * $this->height;
    }
}


$foo = new Triangle(4, 13);
echo $foo->getArea();
```

I would also highly recommend you to alter you other classes too so that the parameters like `$radius` and `$length` are also passed in their respective constructors. Otherwise you are currently breaking *Open-Closed Principle*.

[image]